# how to hide menu in default Contact Screen in Android?

Tags: android

I want to hide menu in default contact screen when we call intent for default contact screen than menu should be hide.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you Please rephrase your question

Comment: Programmatically when we call default contact activity for edit at that time I want whatever menu open(By pressing menu button).that should be hide.I think now you understand

Comment: Also, you should accept answers to your questions if you've found them to be useful(See there is a tick there)and also use upvotes. It will help you get more answers for your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function can be used to manipulate what happens when a menu button is pressed 
this following code just adds a message in the log that the menu button is pressed...

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "MENU pressed");
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: It's not working because we are calling default contact activity(other activity).

Comment: are opening phone contact on menu button press or what....am not able to get what you mean by defalut contact activity??

Comment: /****************Open Default Add Screen*******************/
   Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
   startActivityForResult(newIntent, 1);

Comment: That has default functions added to the contacts activity you cannot edit the function of menu button in that because the functions are library defined

Comment: hmmm... may be you are right but I am trying to find out other way to hide or can we get same layout and source?...

Comment: What you can do is that you can retrieve each contact and all its information and then display it in watever manner you want to, use this to get all the contacts and their attributes http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/

Comment: Thanks for u r help Just I want to know that is there any filed in contact data base that knows Contact Updated, Adedd or deleted (Working like flag) ?..